# Convert HTML5 Canvas + Javascript Application into an Executable

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, exe

Is there a way to run html5/js apps/games into an executable rather than a browser?
I've looked into node webkit but doesn't seem like it suits my ambition.

Also tried Electron . but doesn't seem it supports canvas?

I remember a few years back I was able to run one of my canvas applications with an executable made from Visual Studio using I think Basic? I faintly recall.

Comment: If you are talking about mobile look into Apache Cordova and PhoneGap.  You can create an app using html and JS which runs on both platforms (and windows too).

Comment: I already use cordova for mobile, but in this case I want the game to run on an .exe file for simplicity and distribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Electron supports Canvas tags.

## Clone the Quick Start repository

$ git clone https://github.com/ehartford/electron-quick-start

## Go into the repository

$ cd electron-quick-start

## Install the dependencies and run

$ npm install && npm start

## Use electron packager to create a .exe

https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-packager

[image]

Comment: Does this support canvas? Clone works ok, my apps giving a bunch of errors. Still overall confusing though :/

Comment: Nevermind, got it compiled, now just to try to create an .exe :)